# Updating iOS project with ShareKit, lots of warnings

Tags: ios, sharekit

I'm trying to update an iOS project from last year.  When I load it into Xcode 5.1.1, I get about 40 of the following warning messages:

> warning: /Applications/Xcode
>   5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   -dynamic not specified, -all_load invalid /Applications/Xcode 5.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool:
>   -dynamic not specified the following flags are invalid: -ObjC

I even updated to the latest ShareKit and still have the same problem.  I've checked the compiler and architecture settings and they look ok.

Comment: Is this of any help? http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/02/xcode-4-6-libtool-issues/

Comment: Great! Did removing all "Other Linker Flags" work for you then? If so, I'll write an answer for anyone else facing the issue in the future.

Comment: Good to hear - I've added an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you will need to remove "Other Linker Flags" from the build settings of the static library.

You can read more at:
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/02/xcode-4-6-libtool-issues/

[image: Other Linker Flags]